# Lambda Join and Select

Tags: c#, lambda

Please help me out. I have 2 tables and I need to use lambda. The first table needs to be retrieved, but the first and second table has the where part in.

example

```
public class tableone
{
   public string Name;
   public string Surname;
   public int DepartmentNumber;
   public string GroupId;
}

public class Group
{
   public string groupId;
   public string BaseName;
   public string BaseSiteName;
}
```

I need to retrieve the Table one field but with using a where clause of DepartmentNumber and BaseSite

I think I got this part. I have the entity test and

```
  var records = test.tableone.join(test.Group, group => group.groupId, tableone => tableone.GroupId, 
  (group, testone) => new {tableone = tableOne, group = grouptable});
```

I am not sure if that is correct. How can I retrieve one the table one part. Any help will be apprecaited.

Comment: Sorry there must be a where clause filetering from the 2 tables

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing this part of the question, "How can I retrieve one the table one part." Can you try saying it a different way?

Comment: sorry what I meant was I need to retrieve tableone even thought there is a join something like a select(new tableone() {})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code you show is working you can just add the filtering and pull out the table one records like this:

```
var filteredRecords = records
.Where(r => r.tableone.DepartmentNumber == 5 && r.group.BaseSiteName == "Whatever")
.Select(r => r.tableone);
```

You can also filter the tables you are joining before hand:

```
var filteredTableOnes = tableone.Where(t => t.DepartmentNumber == 5);
var filteredGroup = group.Where(g => g.BaseSiteName == "Whatever");
```

Comment: Hi there, it took me relooking at the join, And your "also" works much better and faster, Thanks alot, you are a star.